# Is it possible for a user to have many badges, lots of voted questions and answer and have reputation 1?

Tags: support, reputation, badges, bounties

User [jww](https://stackexchange.com/users/301110/jww?tab=accounts) has plenty of badges on Stack Overflow (57 gold, 298 silver & 650 bronze).
He has 740 questions and 1.752 answers, some having lots of votes and **reputation 1.**

I can see he has: **47 Offered bounties for 4,600 reputation**.
Can that be enough to get such low reputation?

[image: jww]

Comment: Generally that means that the user is temporarily suspended.

Comment: "*This account is [temporarily suspended](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) network-wide. The suspension period ends on Dec 27 at 15:14.*"

Comment: Which are the reasons for a user to be temporarily suspended?

Comment: Mmm... that question and others linked there show what happens and what implies, but not **why** a user is suspended. I am curious to know the reason. Which @Mithical says are private... May be misconduct?

Comment: @nephewtom I'm not sure knowing the reason is very useful. Whatever it was, it can remain between the user and the stack administration. There is hardly anything useful to be gained from this knowledge for others. At the same time, there is a good chance harm to come out of this disclosure. Ultimately, the expectation is reform after a suspension rather than holding this over the user forever. Spreading the "checkered past" around doesn't help with that.

Comment: Well, it is useful to know from my perspective. If the user suspended did something reprobable (rude, forbidden, nasty, [you-adjective]), I would like to know it for NOT doing it. Sometimes something we do not consider reprobable for ourselves is reprobable for some insitution or forum.

Comment: by definition, people are suspended for misconduct. There's no "maybe" about it, that's the only thing people are suspended for. And don't worry, if you start to do something, there's no secret "aha! you did something we don't like that other places think are great!" you'll get plenty of corrections before you're suspended for it, AND when you're suspended (the first time is usually just a week) you'll be told what the issue was. You don't need to know the details of someone else's case to know how to behave.

Comment: I am not interested in knowing a concrete user case, but the misconduct behaviours that cause a suspension.

Comment: @nephewtom That's what the Help Center and Code of Conduct are for.  Also the `faq` tag on this site, MSE, has useful information.  But "misconduct" is "breaking the rules", and the rules are spelled out in the help center and Code of Conduct.

Answer (score 15):

If you visit the profile page of the user in question, you'll see this banner:

> This account is temporarily suspended network-wide. The suspension period ends on Dec 27 at 15:14.

When an account is temporarily suspended, their reputation is reset to 1 until their suspension is over.

Note, though, that suspension reasons are private and you won't get any information by asking why this particular user was suspended.

Comment: What?? One time I saw a suspended user on Arqade and the banner specified that he was suspended for "voting irregularites". Are you sure that suspension reasons are private?

Comment: @mindstormsboi - You can often see a general reason like that, but the details are between the user and moderators. (That reason is generated from whatever template the moderators used when suspending.)

Comment: Where do you see "This account is temporarily suspended [...]". I do not find it in that profile: https://stackexchange.com/users/301110/jww

Comment: @nephewtom - go to any of the per-site profiles (such as on Stack Overflow).